# Is there a trick to allow MySQL to "ignore" a trailing comma in the SET clause of an UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql

From C++, I'm generating an `UPDATE` statement programmatically in a way that makes stripping a trailing comma difficult:

```
UPDATE `myTable` SET 
   `Field1` = "value",
   `Field2` = "value",
   `Field3` = "value",
WHERE `Field4` = "value";
```

Is there some static, no-op key/value pair I can insert after the final column value specification, which would make the trailing comma "okay"? Or will I have to complicate my C++ code to avoid writing it entirely?

Something apparently equivalent to the following invalid approach would be nice.

```
UPDATE `myTable` SET 
   `Field1` = "value",
   `Field2` = "value",
   `Field3` = "value",
--- 1 = 1
WHERE `Field4` = "value";
```

Comment: I wouldn't call a simple `if` statement to *not* add that comma for the last column "*complicated C++ code*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It's complicated when the _very long_ list is generated from a macro in a big table. Duplicating the macro for one final element is suboptimal if there are four or five characters you can dump towards the end of the query. Not every query building function is a simple loop, and sometimes when you're scaling like this even just the branching is less than desired.

Comment: ... especially if there were a space-cheap and time-cheap alternative. Alas, that appears not to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're willing to duplicate a value as Igoel suggests (which may not be ideal if the value is lengthy), **the simple answer is *no***.

One briefly encouraging possibility was the use of [the alias `NEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) to represent the incoming values, so that the final value may be duplicated without actually having to present it in the query again (and I'd hope that this would be taken out by the query optimiser):

```
UPDATE `myTable` SET 
   `Field1` = "value",
   `Field2` = "value",
   `Field3` = "value",
--- `Field3` = NEW.`Field3`
WHERE `Field4` = "value";
```

Alas, this is not supported in an `UPDATE` statement, only inside a trigger body.

You'll have to do the manipulation in your C++ before executing the statement, either through character replacement (`,` for ) or character removal; the former may produce more complex code than you have now, and the latter may be inefficient (depending on the structure of your query-building code), but it's still your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this, given that you will have to do so in your C++ code, and assuming that you are using a `std::ostream` to build up the statement, is to pull back the "put" cursor one byte so that the next character replaces the trailing `,` rather than following it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "UPDATE `myTable` SET ";

    ss << "`A` = \"value\","
       << "`B` = \"value\",";

    ss.seekp(-1, std::ios_base::cur);
    ss << " WHERE `C` = \"value\"";


    std::cout << ss.str() << '\n';
}

// Output: UPDATE `myTable` SET `A` = "value",`B` = "value" WHERE `C` = "value"
```

This may be more feasible and/or efficient than playing with string lengths, depending on what exactly your code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

you could dublicate one of the rows and strip the comma like:

```
UPDATE `myTable` SET 
   `Field1` = "value",
   `Field2` = "value",
   `Field3` = "value",
   `Field3` = "value"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any elegant way to do it inside the mysql query.

In your C++ code, however, there are a number of ways to do this :

- removing the last coma after creating the `SET` clause with an extra coma should be as simple as : `qry[lgth-1] = ' ';` or `qry.erase(qry.length()-1);`
- I imagine you have some sort of loop to build the `SET` clause, checking the index `i` in your loop is the classical way, or build an array of strings and use some `join(stringList, separator)` function

Comment: No, not a loop. Not that simple.

Comment: ... and building an array then joining it is not even nearly as cheap as some hypothetical four or five characters added into the statement body.

Comment: Yeah me too in simple cases. But this is not a simple case :)

Answer (score 0):

You can place comma before data, as follows:

```
UPDATE `myTable` SET 
   `Field1` = "value"
 , `Field2` = "value"
 , `Field3` = "value"
WHERE `Field4` = "value";
```

Comment: That merely moves the problem to the start!